# Why filter always reseted after request? Yii2,pjax

Tags: gridview, filter, yii2, pjax

I have simple yii2 GridView widget, which is covered by Pjax widget.

When i select any option of filter ,then request by pjax is sent. But after updating the content - filter updated too.

The right way for me filter should not be updated and store selected before filter option.

By the way, in GET params all of filter params correctly exists.

Comment: Update your question and provide some code here. How you get query param and build your filter form? Do you use a search class? and ...

Comment: it depends how you are providing the filter is it using the searchmodel or not , you ned to add code

Comment: please show your gridveiw code

Comment: I just forgot to populate attributes of filter model